# Google DNS for localhost

Tags: domain-name-system, php, apache-2.2, localhost

**Updated:**

I want to use Google DNS for my localhost server. Is that possible? The main reason for this is I keep getting the following errors for the functions like `file()`, `fopen()` etc.

> Warning: file(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or
>   service not known in
>   /var/www/html/crawler/classes/internal/crawler.php on line 22

It's related to DNS I think. So thought it might be possible to use the Google DNS to resolve this.

Comment: show us some of the errors, might be easy to fix

Comment: I think "consult your sysadmin" is the only sensible answer here.

Comment: @womble This is my personal machine. So no Sysadmin here. I'm trying to solve and learn.

Comment: Then this question is off-topic for Server Fault, as per [the FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 2):

Can't say I 100% understand your question but if what you're asking is can you set google's DNS servers to be used as your internal server's DNS resolvers then yes - obviously you'll need a valid route to them but yes you can - in fact the machine I'm typing on now does just that.

Comment: Yes. Can you post a guide for that?

Comment: erm...you just set your DNS servers to be 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 - it's that easy. Here's google's own 'how-to' on this but it's super easy; http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using.html

Comment: I guess I'm being stupid here. Soo, the DNS my internet connection is using is the DNS my localhost is using. Is that Right?

Comment: Yes and no. Your localhost probably uses the Router's DNS which uses the ISP's DNS, which uses ... . Or you break the chain by configuring another DNS server on either machine.

Comment: if it's set to get its DNS address via DHCP then probably yes, but you just override that manually.